# Looking for help identifying IGBT

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, identification, igbt

This was in my DC stick welder. There are two but they're both blown up.

This one has some readable letters on it still. I can find many similar ones but none match the bottom number. Any help is appreciated.

Looks as though the numbers say **40N60?D2**. The bottom number is also throwing me off, unsure if it matters but I haven't found an IGBT with those bottom numbers yet.

[image: picture of the IGBT in question]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it's worth doing a thorough check of the remainder of the circuitry in the welder. It's possible that these IGBTs blew as a *symptom* of an issue elsewhere in the circuitry, and if that issue isn't fixed, the next set of IGBTs will blow as well. Conversely, the IGBTs could have caused damage elsewhere when they failed. As far as replacing the IGBTs...

I was able to find a [PDF datasheet for the SGT40N60FD2 from a Ukrainian distributor](https://pdf.voron.ua/files/pdf/SILAN/SGT40N60FD2PN_en.pdf), and 40n60fd2 is a likely guess based on your image and that datasheet.

My instinct is that the second line could be an internal identifier or lot code, since the first line corresponds well to the manufacturer's official part numbering/designation.

Here's the nomenclature from that datasheet:

[image]

We can read 40N6 clearly, the next character is very likely 0, then we have an unknown character followed by D2. The only character we're left wondering about is the speed grade, which could be L/Q/S/F/UF. UF is out of the question since we only have one character, and L isn't a good fit. Based on searching, I can't find an sgt40n60sd2 or sgt40n60qd2 being manufactured or sold, meaning that F seems pretty likely here. Furthermore, even if the old part were S and Q, that would be a slower part anyway.

The final concern is the package type. It looks like your IGBT is mounted in a holder, meaning that the size and spacing of the pins could be important for good mechanical and electrical behavior. Looking at the way the heatsink and pins look, and cross-referencing against pages 7-8 of that datasheet, the TO-3P package (part number SGT40N60FD2**PN**) looks likely.

SGT40N60FD2**PT** could probably fit if -PN wasn't available, but I wouldn't be as sure about SGT40N60FD2**P7**, since its minimum lead width of 1.1 mm is greater than the nominal lead width of the other two packages.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I really appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: Closely inspecting OP's photo seems to yield "S" as the most likely speed grade. There is a hint of a curve in the only part of the character we can see, making F unlikely, and the curve definitely doesn't continue down on the right, ruling out a Q.